# Deuce and trey - do any other kinds of pip cards have special names?

Tags: vocabulary

I was playing cards this evening and found myself referring to the deuce and the trey. I was wondering, do any of the other pip card ranks have special names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Texas Hold'em, many opening, pre-flop hands (two cards), when paired, seem to have special names:

```
Twos: Deuces, ducks
Threes: Treys, crabs
Fours: Sailboats
Fives: ?
Sixes: ? 
Sevens: Canes, walking sticks
Eights: Snowmen
Nines: ?
Jacks: Hooks
Queens: Ladies (and other, less elegant synonyms)
Kings: Cowboys
Aces: Bullets, Pocket Rockets
```

Additionally, some unpaired hands have special names:

```
Ace-King: Big slick
King-jack: Kojak
5-10: Ben Franklin or Woolworth's or dime store (from 5 & 10 cent store)
```

Comment: Another term for Ace-King is *Anna Kournikova* (looks good but plays terribly / rarely wins).

Comment: These are Hands, not individual Cards?

Comment: @mickey1: They are combinations of cards. In Texas Hold'em, each player is dealt two cards face down. Those are seen only by each the player. The rest of the cards are dealt face up: 3 "on the flop," then 1 "on the turn," then the final card "on the river."

Comment: Wikipedia, of course, has [an extensive list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_playing-card_nicknames) of such nicknames.  My favorite: Q3 is a "San Francisco waiter" (a queen with a trey).  I was unsuccessful in getting my own coinage adopted: AQ being called "Al Qaeda".  Too soon, apparently.

Comment: Ace-King is also jocularly referred to an Anna Kornikova, after the tennis player. She looks good, but she never wins.. :)