# Sice, cinque, cater, trey, deuce, ace, and then?

Tags: vocabulary, old-english, ordinal-numbers

The set of numbers for a six-sided   die are: ace, deuce, trey, cater, cinque, sice. They  originate from Old French (cf. un, deux, trois, quatre, cinq, six in modern French). Ace comes from Latin *as,* *assis* (unity, copper coin, the unit of coinage). They can be mentioned in other situations (e.g. cards) or expressions ("to ace (something): to do exceptionally well"). There are connections with the history of science, since the zero arose quite late in Western countries.

Does  a similar form for the zero exist?

Related questions:

- [Ordinal form of zero (“0”) [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140905/ordinal-form-of-zero-0)
- [1st hour, 2nd hour, 3rd hour… But how to say “zero”-th hour?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106711/1st-hour-2nd-hour-3rd-hour-but-how-to-say-zero-th-hour)
- [“Left with an '8'” meaning of an expression found on a song (by Talk Talk)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336414/left-with-an-8-meaning-of-an-expression-found-on-a-song-by-talk-talk)
- [Deuce and trey - do any other kinds of pip cards have special names?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5624/deuce-and-trey-do-any-other-kinds-of-pip-cards-have-special-names)

Comment: There are no zeroes on dice.

Comment: @JohnLawler No kidding? "Ace" does not exist on dice only: for instance cards.

Comment: Playing cards don't have a zero.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I am providing context for substantives. Not trying to find inexistent sides or cards.

Comment: While the terms ace, deuce, trey, cater, cinque and sice have been made obsolete by one to six, they are still used by some professional gamblers to designate different sides of the dice. ***Ace is from the Latin as, meaning "a unit";***  the others are 2 to 6 in old French. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice

Comment: @LaurentDuval The unstated implication is: if there was no everday object for the word you're seeking to describe, then such a word (ie in the same register) may not exist.

Comment: Western culture gambled with dice long before they were introduced to the Hindu concept of zero. The natural numbers start with 1; there is no zero.

Comment: @DanBron Possibly! Just a question for which I do not have an answer. There are connections with the history of science, since the zero arose quite late in Western countries

Comment: @JohnLawler Which does not hinders the existence of a novel term. Languages evolve

Comment: Related: [Why is a zero score in tennis or squash called love?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/73737/26083)

Comment: @Scott +1 I was not aware of the *l'œuf* origin. However, how does an egg stand the "-th"?

Comment: Since we're talking about eggs, I propose '[duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_(cricket))' for zero.

Comment: @LaurentDuval: I don’t understand why you’re asking about “egg” + “-th”.  The ordinal form of “zero” is “zeroth”.  There aren’t ordinal (-st, -nd, -rd, or -th) forms of “ace”, “deuce”, “trey”, “cater”, “cinque”, and “sice”, are there?

Comment: @Keepthesemind: Actually, [“goose egg”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goose-egg) is slang for “zero” (in English).

Comment: @Scott My initial concern was about: should one write "zeroth-order" or "zero-order", on the expression "Zeroth-order hold" or  "Zero-order hold"? I thought "Zeroth" was correct, but common online knowledge gives  "Zero-order hold" a win? Then my mind wandered....

Comment: @LaurentDuval: I know whereof you speak — I've lost my mind. It wandered off last year, and I haven't seen it since.   :-)   ⁠

Comment: If by "a similar form" you mean "1 is to 0, as ace is to...?" then you already have some good answers (like "love") but the obvious missing two are, from playing cards: "Joker", and, from games of all sorts, "nought," as in Noughts and Crosses, etc.

Comment: "Cipher" is a synonym of "zero." but at least historically it is more the name of the numeral than of the number. Here is the 2nd sentence of Liber Abaci: With these nine figures and with the sign 0, which the Arabs call "zephir," any number whatsoever is written, as is demonstrated below. I'm not the scorekeeper, but I would say "cipher" is worth at least a goose egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question might be paraphrased:

> Complete the pattern with a word that played a parallel historical role:
>
> - *count*: three, two, one, zero
> - *rank*:  third, second, first, zeroth
> - *dice*:  trey, deuce, ace, ____

Briefly, there is no exact fit because [historically, dice didn't have 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#History) until perhaps as late as the mid-20th century, ditto playing cards, etc. etc.

However, some candidates for near matches:

1. **"nought" / "naught"** -- Old English word meaning "nothing" that [came to mean "zero" sometime in the 15th century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nought). Featured in games such as Noughts and Crosses, so nought / ace / deuce....
2. **"love"** -- tennis word for zero, and tennis is a medieval French that emerged in the 15th century and uses the the words ace and deuce, so there you have it. [Etymological theories](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/why-do-they-say-love-fifteen-in-tennis) are that the term "love" either means "no money" or that it is a corruption of the French word for egg (l'œuf), indicateing an egg-shaped zero (also termed a "goose-egg").
3. **"joker"** -- a specially named card (like the "ace") with no numerical marking (so perhaps like zero). A counterargument is that the [origin of the joker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_(playing_card)) is relatively recent (19th century), even if it might be modeled on the Fool tarot, and furthermore that the joker's origin and gameplay use puts it closer to meaning "infinity" (an uber-trump) than to "zero".

Comment: To be more like zero there'd need to be four jokers; one for each suit. I tend to think of jokers as wild cards- being able to stand for any existing value rather than zero.

Comment: One zero-card per suit would *also* be interesting, but it isn't required for the zero card concept, for the same reason that we don't need +0 and -0. So, if I have a box of 2 diamonds, and a box of 3 clubs, and a box of nothing, it isn't automatic to say "what *kind* of nothing? No diamonds, or no clubs?" It could just be: nothing.